# Metrics filter in Graphite - ignore hierarchy (dots)

Tags: wildcard, metrics, graphite, statsd

Is there any way to filter metrics in Graphite while ignoring the hierarchy?

For example:
Say I have the following metrics:

```
stats_count.A.B.TestMetric 
stats_count.A.TestMetric
stats.A.B.TestMetric
stats.A.B.TestMetric
```

How can I sum TestMetric under **stats_count only**?

I tried the followings with no success:

```
stats_counts.*.*.TestMetric - obviously this won't work...
sumSeriesWithWildcards(stats_counts.[A-Z\.]*[A-Z]*.TestMetric,1)
sumSeriesWithWildcards(stats_counts.[A-Z]*[.]*[A-Z]*.TestMetric,1)
```

Any ideas? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Do A and B take a fixes set of values, or are they unknown?

Comment: They should be considered unknown (otherwise I could just use some "or" condition by "duplicate" the filter). The only known names are stats_count + TestMetric. I want to solve it in a general way - which means to be able to sum even series like: stats_count.*.*.*.*.TestMetric

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think what you want is possible. Graphite is very much designed around consistent, unified path schemes.

Comment: That is the conclusion that I came to also... Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a graphite installation (version 0.9.9) where I create metrics on a lot of small systems

For example, I have 2 installations of a postgresql database (postgresql-1 and postgresql-2) where the second is a slave replication of the first. The first database is used for day to day use while the second is a hot standby used mostly by reporting systems and debugging queries

I think the following example is somewhat what you want to do. The image is the amount of connections on both databases. The blue line is on the first, the green line is on the second while the red line is the sum of both series, giving the total amount of connections

```
database.postgresql-1.connection.ALL.value              # blue line
database.postgresql-2.connection.ALL.value              # green line
sumSeries(database.postgresql-*.connection.ALL.value)   # red line
```

[image: amount of connections]

Your problem is that your series have different path levels (I tried to avoid that on my series names as indeed it causes problems). I dont see any other option than writing something like this:

given

```
stats_count.A.B.TestMetric 
stats_count.A.TestMetric
stats.A.B.TestMetric
stats.A.B.TestMetric
```

sum stats_count.**.TestMetric metrics using

```
sumSeries(stats_count.*.TestMetric, stats_count.*.*.TestMetric)
```

Graphite still needs a lot of improvement and unfortunately the development is going quite slowly (for instance version 0.9.10 is the latest release, has problems to install and is from 1 year ago). I am indeed considering forking/contributing to this project

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Currently your workaround quite solve the problem. That's the "OR" condition which I've mentioned in my comments above. So indeed Graphite doesn't support this currently. Thanks again!